# keep track of connected users on iOS application

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7

I have a iOS app, the users can login and logout whenever they want.
In server side, I want to know which users are online.

I could do something like set the user online when the login webservice is called, and set it offline when the logout webservice is called. But, I can't be sure that the logout is always done, maybe the cellphone suddenly turned off, so the server will keep the user online, and when they try to login again he will get the error "sorry, you are already logged in"

Maybe I can do something with the feedback server (my app uses push notifications) but I don't know how fast it detects the user has gone offline...

Comment: Why do you want to prevent login if already logged in - sounds like a maintenance issue. Also, have you thought about a watchdog checking in with the server?

Comment: Yes, but the app need to run in background, so i cant have a watchdog always telling the server "im still online"...

Comment: Its a GPS tracking application wich sends the location to the server, there cant be two open sessions for the same user because both locations will be received and that is not ok..

Comment: So you already have a watchdog in effect, your issue is if the user stops moving. If they try to login again why not invalidate the previous login and stop recording any updates from that login?

Comment: The idea of invaidate the previous login is great!

Comment: Now, i have the issue when the user stos moving. How to disern between a offline user and one sitting on a chair?

Comment: If you're happy with invalidating a previous login then just leave the session active and don't mind about the time between position updates.

Comment: But i distinguish the online users mainly for their ability to recevie a new push notification (a new solicitation) , not for their ability to send server their location. So, do you think i can use the APNS feedback server to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In these cases I think the best think to do is that your App should ping your server every X seconds and update a kind of "last_online" field.

Then in your logic, you can consider for example that a user last seen online more than 3 minutes ago is to be considered offline.

Like you said, you can't trust the user to click "logout" so you can't assume that's the time he logged out.

Of course you can still let the user click logout manually.

Comment: That would be nice, but the app need to run on background, and ios doest allow you to have a eternal service running..

Comment: If the app is in the background, isn't it equivalent to being offline?

Comment: How do you track the location? Doesn't it need to talk to your server?

Comment: Yep! see the above discusion with Wain!